# How to interpret a type which is a dynamic trait object composed from multiple traits in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to understand clearly how to interpret the following line of Rust code:

```
Box<dyn std::any::Any + Send + Sync + 'static>
```

There are multiple keywords here:

- `dyn`
- `Any`
- `Send`
- `Sync`
- `'static`

Three of them are traits, one is a lifetime and finally we have the keyword `dyn`.

How should this be interpreted when these things are composed together?

Comment: I think the [reference on trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) explains this quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down.

```
Box<T>
```

is a `Box` type which takes a template parameter (aka generic) `T`. In this case

```
T = dyn Any + Send + Sync + 'static
```

`'static` is a lifetime. It tell us that `T` is constrained such that if it is a reference, then it must have static lifetime, or if it is not a reference, then any references it contains, must have static lifetime.

- In this expression the lifetime parameter can be considered independently of the rest of the contents. In other words, `'static` can be considered independently to `dyn Any + Send + Sync`. We can think about one of these concepts, and then the others, separately.

We are left with: `dyn Any + Send + Sync`

- How should this be interpreted?

Is it `dyn Any` plus `Send` plus `Sync`, or is it `dyn (Any + Send + Sync)`?

`dyn` marks `T` as being a trait object. That means `&dyn T` is a fat pointer, with a pointer to some data, and a pointer to some `vtable` like object which contains executable code for relevant functions we may wish to call in combination with the data. (See also: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html)

`Box<dyn T>` behaves similarly to `&dyn T`.

So, we know that `&dyn T` is a 16 byte block of memory containing two pointers, one for data and one for code, and that any type associated to the data must be bound by the static lifetime, which constrains the lifetime of any associated references. `Box<dyn T>` is essentially a type which wraps this reference type.

This suggests the correct interpretation is to consider `dyn` independently of any traits which follow, because `&dyn` *means the TYPE `T` IS a fat pointer*, and that the traits can in fact be aggregated together to produce some new trait.

For example, we may replace `Any + Send + Sync` with some new thing:

```
trait X : Any + Send + Sync { }
```

Resulting in `Box::<dyn X + 'static>`. The three keywords `dyn`, `X` and `'static` are independent things which constrain the type `T`.

It is important to realize there are several concepts at play here:

- The type, aka data layout in memory (which here is a fat pointer, `&dyn T`, this implies both the type of data referenced, `T` as well as the functions (behavior) associated via the vtable)
- The trait constraints
- The lifetime constraint on any associated references

The trait just constrains what type of things can be pointed at by the fat pointer. It may for example enforce that certain functions be defined and certain behavior be obeyed or implemented.

Comment: `T = dyn ...` isn't a fat pointer, `&T` or `Box<T>` are if `T` is a [DST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html)

Comment: @cafce25 updated to clarify, thanks for noticing that, it should have said `dyn T` is a fat pointer with type `T`

Comment: My point is `dyn Trait` **isn't** a fat pointer, it's a trait object which is a DST, a pointer to `dyn Trait` is a fat pointer, not the thing itself.

Comment: @cafce25 I've updated the answer to reflect that - if there are any remaining inconsistencies please draw my attention to them so I can fix it.

Comment: "dyn T is a fat pointer", "dyn means the TYPE T IS a fat pointer", "so, we know that dyn T is a 16 byte block" I  wouldn't say you've fixed it...

Comment: "tell us that T is constrained such that if it is a reference, then it must have static lifetime" isn't exactly true for any old lifetime either, `+ 'any_lifetime` means all references have to live at least as long as `'any_lifetime`, not be that lifetime exactly.

Comment: neither `X` nor `'static` are keywords btw

Comment: @cafce25 I sort of agree with you, and sort of don't. Here's why: Yes I see your point and agree that `&dyn T` is a fat pointer, while `dyn T` isn't *exactly* a fat pointer. `dyn T` is called a "trait object"... but as far as I can tell this is a meaningless concept in of itself. It only becomes meaningful as part of a reference or inside a `Box` type. So: `&dyn T` is a reference to a trait object, which is also a fat pointer. `dyn T` is just a trait object. But you can't create one. So it doesn't really have a meaningful interpretation in the language.

Comment: @cafce25 My point being that `dyn T` pretty much implies one of `&dyn T` or `Box<dyn T>`, because there is no other way to "use" it. So, since you can't have `dyn T` on its own, to say "it is a fat pointer" should provide enough information for someone to understand the intent being inferred. However, I will update the answer slightly to make it more technically accurate.

Comment: @cafce25 I've now updated it so that it better reflects technical accuracy by putting the reference in most places where `dyn` exists.

Answer (score 0):

`Box<dyn std::any::Any + Send + Sync + 'static>` can be interpreted as a heap-allocated type that can be any type (`Any`) is safe to transfer ownership of between threads (`Send`) is safe to share references to between threads (`Sync`) and that lives for the entire duration of the program (`'static`).

Meaning you can store any thread-safe data in this `Box` and it can be accessed from any thread.